# Can't use superscripts in Parameter tables in documentation

Tags: bug, documentation

Using the `<sup>` tags inside a Parameter table causes this error to appear when submitting an edit for review:

> Parameters must be formatted as a two column table

For example, `O(n<sup>2</sup>)` fails but `O(n^2)` works fine.